# Gitweb not displaying correctly

Tags: linux, gitweb, lighttpd

I tried setting up gitweb, but when I load the page, it comes out weird...

[image]

---

**Edit:** In case people misunderstood, this is what it should look like:
[image]

---

This is what my lighttpd configuration file looks like:

```
server.port = 80
server.username = "http"
server.groupname = "http"
server.document-root = "/usr/share/gitweb"
server.errorlog = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
dir-listing.activate = "enable"
index-file.names = ( "gitweb.cgi" )
cgi.assign = (
    ".cgi" => ""
)
mimetype.assign = (
    ".html" => "text/html",
    ".txt" => "text/plain",
    ".jpg" => "image/jpeg",
    ".png" => "image/png"
)
server.modules += (
    "mod_cgi",
    "mod_setenv"
)
setenv.add-environment = (
    "GITWEB_CONFIG" => "/etc/conf.d/gitweb.conf"
)
```

This is what gitweb.conf looks like:

```
$git_temp = "/tmp";

# The directories where your projects are. Must not end with a slash.
$projectroot = "/path/to/projects";

# Base URLs for links displayed in the web interface.
our @git_base_url_list = qw(git://localhost http://git@localhost);
```

(`/path/to/projects` is just to give you an idea.)

When I use `git instaweb`, it seems to come out fine, although it looks like it's ignoring the new gitweb.css file that I'm trying to use. **Edit:** It's because I didn't update the cache.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried bypassing the cache after modifying the stylesheet? (Ctrl + R or Ctrl + F5)

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Oh, right. Thank you :). That solves the instaweb problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that CSS documents aren't being recognized properly.

```
mimetype.assign = (
    ".html" => "text/html",
    ".txt" => "text/plain",
    ".jpg" => "image/jpeg",
    ".png" => "image/png",
    ".css" => "text/css"
)
```

The mime type needed to be set.

Answer (score 0):

`gitweb` works only on **bare repositories**. So make sure you have one.  Your screen-shot looks like you have created one repository with full working tree, and pointing to this directory.

**EDIT**
The current version of gitweb works on non-bare also, but your system may have an older one.

The missing name of the repository could be configured in your git-config:

```
[gitweb]
  description = "My Repository Description"
  cloneurl    = git://here.you.could/clone/me.git
  owner       = "Me"
```

There are more config parameters available, just have a look at the documentation (under /usr/share/doc/git*)

Comment: That's right, it isn't a bare repository. Are you sure that would solve the problem, though? I thought this would have something to do with my lighttpd/gitweb configuration.

Comment: @someguy Updated my post. To work with a bare repostory should work always. Make sure that your Path is pointing to the **parent** directory, not to the repository.

Comment: I'm using git 1.7.6, which is the latest stable version. I've updated my question showing what it *should* look like in case you misunderstood the problem. I've tried pointing to the parent directory and it's the same problem.